# I'm trying to write a program to test the accuracy percentage of 8 sets of security codes

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I need help writing a program bellow has to test the accuracy percentage of 8 sets of security codes each containing 10 integer values in java (data structure)

```
public class lab_three_solution {
    /* Solution method: Complete this method only. Also add a relevant parameter to this method*/
    
    public static void compare(){
              
    }

    /* Main method: Pass the Security Codes as an argument when calling the 'compare' method */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // 8 Security Codes to compare
        int[][] security_codes = {{0,1,1,7,7,2,2,5,0,3}, {5,1,4,0,5,0,9,8,7,5}, {9,8,3,4,0,9,6,7,7,1},
                {5,9,5,7,1,4,9,7,6,9}, {7,1,1,4,6,7,9,1,1,0}, {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1}, {6,1,1,8,4,9,7,0,1,2},
                {9,5,4,6,3,1,4,7,2,9}};

        compare(security_codes);
    }
}
```

The accuracy is determined by comparing the sequence of each of the 8 codes against the
sequence of correct code shown below

**correct** = {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1}

I have to design and implement an algorithm in JAVA that prints out the accuracy as
a percentage by comparing each of the 8 security codes against the 1 acceptable code. i.e. if
say Security Code 6 sequence matches the sequence of the acceptable code then my output
should be “Security Code 1 is 100% accurate”

Comment: Is accuracy calculated by the matches divided by the total items in the array?

Comment: Sure, So that we can get an answer in percentages

Comment: What specific help do you need? What have you tried? What did it do that wasn’t as you expected? What did you do to try remedy this?

Comment: I have tried this inside the compare() ``` public static void compare(){
        int[] code = {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1};
       boolean test = false;
       for(int element : code){
           if(elemet == security_codes)
               test = true;
           break;
       }
       
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Loop through each array
- In each loop, store the number of matches in a variable, and increment this variable when the current number being looped through is equal to the number at the same index in the `correct` array
- Calculate the accuracy by dividing the matches by the length of the array

```java
static final int[] correct = {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1};
public static void compare(int[][] a){
    for(int[] b : a) {
        int matches = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            matches += correct[i] == b[i] ? 1 : 0;
        }
        double accuracy = matches * 1.0 / b.length;
        System.out.println(accuracy);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] security_codes = {
            {0,1,1,7,7,2,2,5,0,3},
            {5,1,4,0,5,0,9,8,7,5},
            {9,8,3,4,0,9,6,7,7,1},
            {5,9,5,7,1,4,9,7,6,9},
            {7,1,1,4,6,7,9,1,1,0},
            {6,1,1,6,3,1,4,7,7,1},
            {6,1,1,8,4,9,7,0,1,2},
            {9,5,4,6,3,1,4,7,2,9}};
    compare(security_codes);
}
```

Result:

```
0.2
0.2
0.3
0.1
0.2
1.0
0.3
0.5
```